# Cells will not turn green when altered

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet set up that only has certain cells unlocked for editing on an otherwise locked sheet. All of these cells are originally colored yellow, and are empty. My goal is to get the cells to turn from their base color of yellow to green when any data is entered into them, and to stay green as long as it contains any type of data, but to turn back to yellow if data is removed. I have written code for this and I cannot see what the problem is, so I must be missing something, because the code does not do what I want it to, and only gets an error message instead. This code is located in my main workbook code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Worksheet.Index = 3 Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The error I get says "Runtime error "1004": Application-defined or object-defined error, and occurs in line 5:
    Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6.
If anyone can give me a hand with this I would appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting?

Comment: When the error shows, what do you see in the immediate window if you type `? Target.address`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad has the efficient fix...  Specific to your post, i'm not getting an issue.  I have copied and pasted your macro in my `ThisWorkbook` and it works just fine, provided I am on sheets(3) and any cell i have entered (f2 to edit) and left blank turns yellow and if I add a value it turns green.  My only color-related issue is if I copy/paste cells in sheets(3) and the paste is GREEN, despite copying blank cells.

Comment: I've never used conditional formatting before. I'm not looking for any specific values, I just want it to change color if ANY data (numerical or otherwise) is put into the cell. Could anyone help me with the formatting to accomplish this?

Comment: Use conditional formatting with the following formula: `=LEN(A1)>0` See [this sample](https://imgur.com/a/WxOn2Lf)

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Thank you for the help! @cybernetic.nomad & Cyril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of days ago I faced the same problem. The thing is when the sheet is protected there is no way to alter the format of a certain cell. It does not matter if the cell is locked or unlocked.

An easy way to change the color would be to use conditional formatting.
1. select cell you want to format
2. Set new rule so the cell when is empty it is filled yello and when it is filled with somehting it turns green.

```
=A1="" then format yellow
=A1<>"" then format green
```

The other thing you can try is to unlock and lock the worksheet when you want it to turn into new color. However I think this will only work if you are using a macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Destino As Workbook

Destino.ActiveShee.Unprotect("password")

If Target.Worksheet.Index = 3 Then
    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
End If

Destino.ActiveShee.protect("password")

End Sub
```

Those are my answers for you